# Adding Product Variant and Related Product to the cart together on Craft Commerce 2

Tags: relations, plugin-craftcommerce2, variants

I want to add a product variant as well as a related product (chosen from a select list) together when the user clicks the add to cart button.

I can see you can add multiple products together with Commerce 2.
But I am stuck as to where to start with this. Can anyone point me in the right direction. here is some of my starting code:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/update-cart">
  {{ redirectInput('shop/cart') }}
  <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1">
  {{ csrfInput() }}
  <div class="field">
    <select name="purchasableId">
      {% for purchasable in product.variants %}
        <option {% if purchasable.stock
                  <= 0 and purchasable.hasUnlimitedStock == false %}disabled {% endif %}
                value="{{ purchasable.id }}"
        >{{ purchasable.sku }} {{ purchasable.description }} {{ purchasable.price|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <select name="purchasableId">
      <option value="">No Bolts</option>
      {% for product in product.fixingAddOn %}
        {% for purchasable in product.variants %}
          <option
            value="{{ purchasable.id }}"
          >
            {{ purchasable.id }} - {{ purchasable.price|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}
            {{ product.title }}
          </option>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>

  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    <input type="hidden" name="purchasables[{{ loop.index }}][id]" value="{{ variant.id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="purchasables[{{ loop.index }}][qty]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="purchasables[{{ loop.index }}][note]" value="1">
  {% endfor %}

  <div class="buttons">
    <label for="qty" class="alt">Qty</label>
    <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty" min="1" class="qty" placeholder="Qty" value="1" />

    <input type="submit" value="{{ " Add to cart"|t }}" class="button" />
  </div>
</form>
```

**EDIT** 
I have the following now working but would there be a better approach to this?

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="commerce/cart/update-cart">
  {{ redirectInput('shop/cart') }}
  <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1">
  {{ csrfInput() }}


  <div class="field">
    <select name="purchasables[1][id]">
      {% for purchasable in product.variants %}
        <option {% if purchasable.stock
                  <= 0 and purchasable.hasUnlimitedStock == false %}disabled {% endif %}
                value="{{ purchasable.id }}"
        >{{ purchasable.sku }} {{ purchasable.description }} {{ purchasable.price|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <select name="purchasables[2][id]">
      <option value="">No Bolts</option>
      {% for product in addOns %}
        {% for purchasable in product.variants %}
          <option
            value="{{ purchasable.id }}"
          >
            {{ purchasable.id }} - {{ purchasable.price|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}
            {{ product.title }}
          </option>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>


  <div class="buttons">
    <label for="qty" class="alt">Qty</label>
    <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty" min="1" class="qty" placeholder="Qty" value="1" />

    <input type="submit" value="{{ " Add to cart"|t }}" class="button" />
  </div>
</form>
```